# Filter data according to a selected value, sorting and counted by date in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, formula

In the first column I have a list sorted by the date of several students and its topics requested. As can be seen, the table is arranged by data, name, topic and a checkbox if the question has been solved.

[image]

In the second column, I have a drop down list where I want to select the student and query below his last 15 days requests, checking whether it is completed or not.

[image]

Every time the student is selected, the row A4  will display all his/her topics sorted from the latest 15 days, and the cells F3 and F4 will count according to total and solveds.

Is that possible to apply it via formula?

Here is the file if you need:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7beVyUr0pEUoRSgqQYYOi0y0Sbd8scC3B825GKA3sQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your column A on Control sheet contains a mixture of dates and text strings (invalid dates) so the formula needs to be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SORT({IFNA(IF(N(Control!A2:A)<>0; Control!A2:A; DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "/(\d+) "); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "/(\d+)/"); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "^\d+"))+
 INDEX(SPLIT(Control!A2:A; " ");;2)))\ Control!B2:D}; 1; 0); 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col2 = '"&A1&"' limit 15"; 0))
```

[image]

---

F3:

```
=COUNTA(B4:B)
```

F4:

```
=COUNTIF(C4:C; TRUE)
```

Comment: Awesome, however, there is a problem when selecting John. I tried to through the limit in the count, however, no success. Why is John returning error?

Comment: What error is it returning and where? Be specific please?

Comment: @CaioFerrari fixed and answer updated. see your sheet