# Find the last 10 days from today and query in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this sheet here set in a tab named Reports:

[image]

As can be seen, column A contains the date and time of the report. The most recent has been set on February 16th and the oldest is January 28th.

I would like to query the last 10 days, starting from today in another tab. So, if today is February 17th, I need all the reportes queried until February 7th.

Note: I don't need the last 10 reports, I need the last 10 days, no matter how many is accumulated.

I tried something like this:

```
=QUERY(SORT({
'Reports'!A1:A;
}, 1, 0),
"where Col2 is not null limit 10", 0)
```

Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7beVyUr0pEUoRSgqQYYOi0y0Sbd8scC3B825GKA3sQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You've got a lot of problems with your date data. Half of the dates are text, not real dates. The other half are numbers, but not in a format recognized by your country. How is this information getting into your sheet? Also, your sheet is currently set to "View only"; so neither I nor anyone else can access your sheet to test formulas or leave notes. Please change your link permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUERY({Report!A1:B} ; "SELECT * 
WHERE Col2 is not null AND Col1 >= date '" 
& TEXT(NOW()-10; "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({Report!A1:B};
 "where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-10; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY();    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)
```

[image]

---

or from Control sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(IF(N(Control!A2:A)<>0; Control!A2:A; DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "/(\d+) "); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "/(\d+)/"); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(Control!A2:A; "^\d+"))+
 INDEX(SPLIT(Control!A2:A; " ");;2)))\ Control!B2:B}; 
 "where Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE(TODAY()-10)&"
    and Col1 <= "&DATEVALUE(TODAY())&"
  format Col1 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss'"; 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work. I just updated the question and added the URL to access!

Comment: Hey, @player0, see my comment to the OP re: the date formatting.

Comment: Me again, @player0. I should also note that the poster is in Brazil; so all formulas are in the semicolon-for-comma (etc) format. Just a heads-up to save you time if you continue to pursue solutions on this.

Comment: @ErikTyler thx for the heads up. it looked familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179934/5632629 ...anyway sheet named Report has all nice dates - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mewGA.png

Comment: @player0, I'm confused now as to how and where data will actually be coming into this sheet (or the real-world equivalent). I see that the "Report" sheet has clean data as you noted. But who made that? How did it get there (there are no formulas in that sheet)? Does that accurately represent how and where real data will come into the sheet? At any rate, without all the wondering, seems the problem has been addressed given what we've been given.

Comment: @ErikTyler not sure either, but let's hope OP knows what to do :D